# Monotouch: Relational items positioning inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

How to align images and texts depending on their presence. For instance I have 2 images and I need to place them vertically one above the other but when any one is missing (not provided) the other one should be centered vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assumes you have you basic imageview frame setup (size and x position). 
It puts a collection of views vertically in the view with equal spacing. It even centers if the collection has just one image.

```
    UIImageView img1, img2;
        List<UIView> subViews;

        if (img1 != null)
        {
            subViews.Add(img1);
        }


        if (img2 != null)
        {
            subViews.Add(img2);
        }

        float totalHeight = 0;

        foreach (UIView subView in views)
        {
            totalHeight += subView.Frame.Height;                
        }

        float spacing = (this.Bounds.Height - totalHeight) / (subView.Length +1) ;
        float currentY = 0;

        foreach (UIView subView in subViews)
        {
            currentY += spacing;

            if (subView.Superview == null)
            {
                this.Add (subView);
            }

            subView.Frame = new RectangleF(subView.Frame.X,currentY,subView.Frame.Width, subView.Frame.Height);

            currentY += subView.Frame.Height;

        }
```